# La query da error y no entiendo porque

Tags: sql, spring-boot

Estoy realizando un proyecto con Springboot y una de las query da error. Os pongo en contexto, tengo hospitales medico paciente citas e informes. En nuestro caso solo nos interesa las medico paciente y citas ya que estos se relacionan a traves de la citas.Os dejo la query y las clases, si necesitais algo mas pedirlo.

```
 @Repository
    public interface CitaRepository extends JpaRepository<Cita, Integer> {
    
      @Query("Select m from Medico m "
            + "where m.listaCitas.paciente.nSS= :nSS and m.especialidad= 'cabecera'"))   
        public int buscarMmedico(@Param("nSS") String nSS);
        
    }
```

clase medico

```
    @Entity
@Table(name = "medico")
public class Medico implements Serializable, Logable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 3L;
    @Id
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(name = "n_licencia")
    private String nLicencia;
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(name = "nombre")
    private String nombre;
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(name = "especialidad")
    private String especialidad;
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(name = "consulta")
    private int consulta;
    @Column(name = "password", nullable = false)
    private String password;
    @JoinColumn(name = "nombre_hos")
    @ManyToOne(optional = true)
    private Hospital hospital;
    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "medico")
    private List<Cita> listaCitas;
    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "medico")
    private List<Informe> listaInformes;

    public Medico() {
        this.listaInformes = new ArrayList<>();
        this.listaCitas = new ArrayList<>();
    }

    public Medico(String nLicencia, String nombre, String especialidad, int consulta, String password, Hospital hospital, List<Cita> listaCitas, List<Informe> listaInformes) {
        this.nLicencia = nLicencia;
        this.nombre = nombre;
        this.especialidad = especialidad;
        this.consulta = consulta;
        this.password = password;
        this.hospital = hospital;
        this.listaCitas = listaCitas;
        this.listaInformes = listaInformes;
    }

    public String getnLicencia() {
        return nLicencia;
    }

    public void setnLicencia(String nLicencia) {
        this.nLicencia = nLicencia;
    }

    public String getNombre() {
        return nombre;
    }

    public void setNombre(String nombre) {
        this.nombre = nombre;
    }

    public String getEspecialidad() {
        return especialidad;
    }

    public void setEspecialidad(String especialidad) {
        this.especialidad = especialidad;
    }

    public int getConsulta() {
        return consulta;
    }

    public void setConsulta(int consulta) {
        this.consulta = consulta;
    }

    public Hospital getHospital() {
        return hospital;
    }

    public void setHospital(Hospital hospital) {
        this.hospital = hospital;
    }

    public List<Cita> getListaCitas() {
        return listaCitas;
    }

    public void setListaCitas(List<Cita> listaCitas) {
        this.listaCitas = listaCitas;
    }

    public List<Informe> getListaInformes() {
        return listaInformes;
    }

    public void setListaInformes(List<Informe> listaInformes) {
        this.listaInformes = listaInformes;
    }
    
    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }

    @Override
    public String getIdentifier() {
        return getnLicencia();
    }
}
```

Paciente

```
    @Entity
@Table(name = "paciente")
public class Paciente implements Serializable, Logable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 4L;
    @Id
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(name = "nss")
    private String nSS;
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(name = "nombre")
    private String nombre;
    @Column(name = "password")
    private String password;
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(name = "f_nacimiento")
    @Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
    private Date fNacimiento;
    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "paciente")
    private List<Cita> citas;
    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "paciente")
    private List<Informe> informes;

    public Paciente() {
        this.informes = new ArrayList<>();
        this.citas = new ArrayList<>();
    }

    public Paciente(String nSS, String nombre, String password, Date fNacimiento, List<Cita> citas, List<Informe> informes) {
        this.nSS = nSS;
        this.nombre = nombre;
        this.password = password;
        this.fNacimiento = fNacimiento;
        this.citas = citas;
        this.informes = informes;
    }
   
    public String getnSS() {
        return nSS;
    }

    public void setnSS(String nSS) {
        this.nSS = nSS;
    }

    public String getNombre() {
        return nombre;
    }

    public void setNombre(String nombre) {
        this.nombre = nombre;
    }

    public Date getfNacimiento() {
        return fNacimiento;
    }

    public void setfNacimiento(Date fNacimiento) {
        this.fNacimiento = fNacimiento;
    }

    public List<Cita> getCitas() {
        return citas;
    }

    public void setCitas(List<Cita> citas) {
        this.citas = citas;
    }
 
    public List<Informe> getInformes() {
        return informes;
    }

    public void setInformes(List<Informe> informes) {
        this.informes = informes;
    }

    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }

    @Override
    public String getIdentifier() {
        return getnSS();
    }
}
```

Y citas

```
    @Entity
@Table(
        name = "cita",
        uniqueConstraints = {
            @UniqueConstraint(columnNames = {"n_licencia", "nss", "f_hora_cita"}),
            @UniqueConstraint(columnNames = {"n_licencia", "f_hora_cita"}),
            @UniqueConstraint(columnNames = {"nss", "f_hora_cita"})
        }
)
public class Cita implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 5L;
    @Id
    @Basic(optional = false)
    private int id;
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(name = "f_hora_cita")
    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    private Date fHoraCita;
    @JoinColumn(name = "nss", referencedColumnName = "nss")
    @ManyToOne(optional = false)
    private Paciente paciente;
    @JoinColumn(name = "n_licencia", referencedColumnName = "n_licencia")
    @ManyToOne(optional = false)
    private Medico medico;

    public Cita() {
    }

    public Cita(int id, Date fHoraCita, Paciente paciente, Medico medico) {
        this.id = id;
        this.fHoraCita = fHoraCita;
        this.paciente = paciente;
        this.medico = medico;
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public Date getfHoraCita() {
        return fHoraCita;
    }

    public void setfHoraCita(Date fHoraCita) {
        this.fHoraCita = fHoraCita;
    }

    public Paciente getPaciente() {
        return paciente;
    }

    public void setPaciente(Paciente paciente) {
        this.paciente = paciente;
    }

    public Medico getMedico() {
        return medico;
    }

    public void setMedico(Medico medico) {
        this.medico = medico;
    }
}
```

Estos errores da

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'citaRepository': FactoryBean threw exception on object creation; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Validation failed for query for method public abstract com.proyecto.modelos.Medico com.proyecto.repositorios.CitaRepository.buscarMmedico(java.lang.String)!
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Validation failed for query for method public abstract com.proyecto.modelos.Medico com.proyecto.repositorios.CitaRepository.buscarMmedico(java.lang.String)!
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: org.hibernate.QueryException: illegal attempt to dereference collection [medico0_.n_licencia.listaCitas] with element property reference [paciente] [Select m from com.proyecto.modelos.Medico m where m.listaCitas.paciente.nSS= :nSS and m.especialidad= 'cabecera']
Caused by: org.hibernate.QueryException: illegal attempt to dereference collection [medico0_.n_licencia.listaCitas] with element property reference [paciente] [Select m from com.proyecto.modelos.Medico m where m.listaCitas.paciente.nSS= :nSS and m.especialidad= 'cabecera']
Caused by: org.hibernate.QueryException: illegal attempt to dereference collection [medico0_.n_licencia.listaCitas] with element property reference [paciente]
```

Comment: Cierto lo olividaba ya esta. Yo no veo el error en la query pero debe de haber alguno

Comment: El alias `M` representa la tabla `medico`. Estás haciendo `m.medico.n_licencia` y creería que el campo es sólo `n_licencia`.

Comment: Te cambio la query para que sea mas sencilla y te pongo los errores

Answer (score 0):

Con indicar en la clase médico que cita es una `List<Cita>` no basta para que se resuelva la relación. Tienes que hacer el join con la colección en vez de intentar dereferenciarla. Algo *parecido* a:

```
Select 
m 
from com.proyecto.modelos.Medico m 
join com.proyecto.modelos.Cita ct
where ct.paciente.nSS = :nSS 
and m.especialidad = 'cabecera'
```

Fuente: [Respuesta en SO original](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24751098/236345)

Comment: Sigue sin valer. Estos son los errores que da con tu query
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'citaRepository': FactoryBean threw exception on object creation; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Validation failed for query for method public abstract com.proyecto.modelos.Medico com.proyecto.repositorios.CitaRepository.buscarMmedico(java.lang.String)!
Ese es uno hay un monton que no pueod ponerlo